# pandas: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'contains'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lowercase

I have the following code to check if the value of certain column contains the given string:

```
my_df[my_df.name.str.contains('Mike')]
```

However, when I tried to make it work for all letter cases like:

```
my_df[my_df.name.str.lower.contains('mike')]
```

I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

What should be the correct way to call the lower() function, so I can make sure the match is case insensitive? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the boolean parameter `case`. It's set to `True` by default, which is case sensitive. Thus, you should set it to `False`. [Pandas Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
my_df[my_df.name.str.contains('Mike', case=False)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
my_df[my_df.name.str.contains('Mike', flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Source: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html